# BibTeX style which shows annotation fields and employs numeric-style citation call-outs

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am relatively new to LaTeX, i have used it for a couple of documents here and there but I am now using it for a formal school report which needs an annotated bibliography.

My current problem is that if I want to have my annotation displayed, the citations keys are now no longers numerical. If I changed my style, my keys are numerical but my annotations are not displayed.

Here is my `bibfile.bib`:

```
@MISC{tJung11,
    author = {Jungblut, Thomas},
    title = {Ant Colony Optimization for TSP Problems},
    month = Aug,
    year = {2011},
    howpublished = {url: http://codingwiththomas.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/ant-colony-optimization-for-tsp.html},
    note = {Accessed: 26-01-2015},
    annotate = {This Blog posted by Thomas Jungblut covers mutliple topics which are of high interest to the projects research.
            The information contained in the blog covers items like capitalising on multi-threading opportunities and how to efficiently do so.
            The underling calculations and evaluation procedures for each agent are also discussed. This is useful for modeling and 
            designing the algorithm itself.}
}
```

and here is the styling i've tried:

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{annotate}
\bibliography{bibfile}
```

which produces:

[image]

and just a simple plain style:

```
   \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{annotate}
    \bibliography{bibfile}
```

which produces this:

[image]

i want a combination of the two so the annotation shows and the key is `[1]` not `[Jun11]`

I have tried looking on websites such as: http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html but I can't seem to locate a solution.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: You could try with `biblatex`, which is relatively easy to customise and defines a `url` and an `annotation` field.

Comment: I'd be much more easier to help if you produce a MWE with the relevant code.

Comment: On the other hand, if you need to print the annotate with another bibliography style, you'd better try biblatex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's the `plain` bibliography style you wish to modify to enable it to print the contents of the `annotate` field, you could proceed as follows:

- Find the file `plain.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file, calling the copy (say) `plainannotate.bst`. (Don't edit a file from the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `plainannotate.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- First, you have to inform `plainannotate` that it's supposed to recognize fields named `annotate`. Near the very top of the file, find the structure named `ENTRY`. Insert a blank line between "address" and "author", and insert the word "annotate" in the new line.
- Second, you have to inform the bibliography style (and BibTeX) what to do when it's told to process the contents of the `annotate` field. Find the definition of the function `format.authors` (ca. line 215 in my copy of the file). After this function (and before the function `format.editors`), insert the following lines of code:

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.annotate}
  { annotate empty$
      { "" }
      { " \begin{quotation}\noindent "
        annotate
        * " \end{quotation} " *
      }
        if$
  }
  ```

  In case you're curious what this code does: It first checks if the `annotate` field is empty. If so, it prints nothing (`""`). If it's non-empty, a `quotation` environment is initiated, the contents of the `annotate` field are written out, and the `quotation` environment is closed.
- Third, we have to modify the functions `article`, `book`, etc, which process the entries of type `@article`, `@book`, etc., and tell them that they're supposed to invoke the newly-created function `format.annotate` at the end of each entry.

  - Find the function `article`. (It should start on line 550 or so if you've been following the instructions so far.) After the line that says `fin.entry`, insert two new lines:

    ```
      format.annotate write$
      newline$
    ```
  - Next, find the function `book`. (It should be the function that immediately follows `article`.) Guess what: After its final line, which is again `fin.entry`, insert two more new lines, with the same contents as for the function `article`:

    ```
      format.annotate write$
      newline$
    ```
  - Ditto for the function `booklet`.
  - For most of the remaining entry-formatting functions, viz., `inbook`, `incollection`, `inproceedings`, `manual`, `mastersthesis`, `phdthesis`, `proceedings`, `techreport`, and `unpublished`, just add one extra line after `fin.entry`, viz.,

    ```
      format.annotate write$
    ```
  - The only entry type that's a bit special is the type `@misc`, since it's BibTeX's "catch-all" entry type. (Entry types that are not recognized, say because they've been mis-spelled by accident, are automatically treated as being of type `@misc`.) Find the function `misc`; it should be between the functions `mastersthesis` and `phdthesis`. Note that this function's final two lines are

    ```
      fin.entry
      empty.misc.check
    ```

    (Because `@misc` is the catch-all entry type, care must be taken if its contents are entirely empty.) In this case, insert the instruction `format.annotate write$` on a new blank line between these two lines, like so:

    ```
      fin.entry
      format.annotate write$
      empty.misc.check
    ```
- Save the file `plainannotate.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex file is located, or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution.
- Start using the "new" bibliography style by providing the instruction `\bibliographystyle{plainannotate}`. Be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to propagate all changes.

Here's an MWE that puts it all together:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{abcdef.bib}
@MISC{tJung11,
    author = {Jungblut, Thomas},
    title = {Ant Colony Optimization for {TSP} Problems},
    month = Aug,
    year = {2011},
    howpublished = {\url{http://codingwiththomas.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/ant-colony-optimization-for-tsp.html}},
    note = {Accessed: 26-01-2015},
    annotate = {This Blog posted by Thomas Jungblut covers mutliple topics which are of high interest to the projects research. The information contained in the blog covers items like capitalising on multi-threading opportunities and how to efficiently do so. The underling calculations and evaluation procedures for each agent are also discussed. This is useful for modeling and designing the algorithm itself.}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainannotate}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\begin{document}
\cite{tJung11}
\bibliography{abcdef}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this problem and answer was completed 4 years ago, but I thought this extra bit of information may save someone else a few hours of hair pulling.

I just tried Mico's plain.bst modification and got a "You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry" error.

After battling with this problem for a while I found I had to add "annotate" to the list of ENTRY labels at the beginning of the modified .bst file to make it work properly... I hope this helps :)

```
    ENTRY
    { address
      annotate
      author
      booktitle
      chapter
      edition
      editor
      howpublished
      institution
      journal
      key
      month
      note
      number
      organization
      pages
      publisher
      school
      series
      title
      type
      volume
      year
     }
     {}
     { label }
```

Comment: I modified my answer to show the section that I put "annotate" in the modified .bst file